# configuring Karma with Jasmine: getJasmineRequireObj is not defined

Tags: configuration, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

It gave me this error:

```
Chrome 37.0.2019 (Mac OS X 10.9.3) ERROR
  Uncaught ReferenceError: getJasmineRequireObj is not defined at /Users/Lucia/Desktop/test-yo-karma/dev/vendors/jasmine/src/core/Spec.js:1
```

But I made sure the file did exist. And couldn't find the error anywhere?

Answer (score 8):

I found i had

```
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'jasmine-ajax'],
```

instead of

```
frameworks: ['jasmine-ajax', 'jasmine'],
```

in my karma.conf

Comment: Had the same problem. That is so annoying

Answer (score 1):

Just spent a good 4 hours dealing with the same issue. There are several things going wrong here (hence all the different, probably equally accurate answers), the core of it being: there are version conflicts requiring specific dependencies for 'jasmine', 'jasmine-ajax', and 'karma-jasmine-ajax'.

I use Jasmine 1.3, and the current version of `karma-jasmine-ajax` depends on a version of `jasmine-ajax` **that is incompatabile with Jasmine 1.3.x**.

This is noted in the `jasmine-ajax` documentation, but not the `karma-jasmine-ajax` documentation: *"This branch is now version 2.0, if you need jasmine-ajax for Jasmine 1.3.x please grab the last release from that tag."*

In order to fix this specific conflict, I specified **`"karma-jasmine-ajax": "0.1.3",`** in my package.json, which pulls in **`jasmine-ajax` version 2.0.0**. This version of `jasmine-ajax` does not use `getJasmineRequireObj`.

If you're loading in `jasmine-ajax` directly, you can use this version: https://raw.github.com/pivotal/jasmine-ajax/v1.3.1/lib/mock-ajax.js

Keep in mind (yet another gotcha) that the different versions of jasmine differ in their usage of `request.response` and `request.RespondWith` -- and this switches back and forth between older and newer versions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I had this in `karma.conf.js`:

```
files: [
  {pattern: 'dev/vendors/**/*.js', included: false},
  {pattern: 'dev/scripts/**/*.js', included: false},
  {pattern: 'test/**/*Spec.js', included: false},
  'test/test-main.js'
]
```

It turns out,

1. the order of files included matters
2. you're not supposed to include irrelevant files (e.g. the whole of `/vendors`)

So I should include separate files, in their order of dependency instead.

[[The unhelpful documentation](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/files.html)]

Answer (score 0):

i saw this error as well, and when i looked through it, it turned out that var TEST_REGEXP in karma.conf.js was too broadly defined and was actually grabbing and executing: my_client/app/bower_components/jasmine/src/core/Spec.js:1

once i changed my TEST_REGEXP to include only my specs (you could also do this by specifically excluding all spec files of vendor directories) the error went away.